# filtering object and modify properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am having a newbie question and I have tried to read the manuals over and over and cannot figure it out.

so I have this code:

```
export function editSerier(data, products) {
    return (dispatch) => {

        const filteredProducts = Object.assign(
            ...Object.keys(products)
                .filter(key => products[key].Artikelgrupp === data.Artikelgrupp)
                .map(k => ({ 
                    [k]: products[k]:{
                    Beskrivning: data.Beskrivning,
                    kategori: data.kategori,
                    status: data.status,
                    synas: data.synas,
                    tillverkare: data.tillverkare,
                    titel: data.titel}
                })

            })



        console.log(filteredProducts)
    }
}
```

Where I want to filter the incoming object products by "Artikelgrupp" and then modify the existent properties of the remaining products with properties from "data".

However this code does not let me run it.
Does someone have any idea?

**UPDATE:
just solved it by merging both objects**

```
const filteredProducts = Object.assign(
            ...Object.keys(products)
                .filter(key => products[key].Artikelgrupp === data.Artikelgrupp)
                .map(k => ({ 
                    [k]: {...products[k], ...data}
                }))
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You have invalid JavaScript. If you want a nested object, you need `{ something: { } }` and if you want to use a computed property name, you need to surround it with `[]`.

So, this will work

```js
export function editSerier(data, products) {
  return dispatch => {
    const filteredProducts = Object.assign(
      ...Object.keys(products)
        .filter(key => products[key].Artikelgrupp === data.Artikelgrupp)
        .map(k => ({
          [k]: {
            [products[k]]: {
              Beskrivning: data.Beskrivning,
              kategori: data.kategori,
              status: data.status,
              synas: data.synas,
              tillverkare: data.tillverkare,
              titel: data.titel
            }
          }
        }))
    );

    console.log(filteredProducts);
  };
}
```

Comment: It works but not the way I want. "Data" object is to be merged into products and not be nested as a nested object

Comment: just solved it but thanks. Your solution, made me realise where the mistake was.

Comment: @OblicionA can you post your solution?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are wanting to obtain a single object which:

- excludes all value objects of `products` where a `Artikelgrupp` field does not match `data.Artikelgrupp` and,
- the specific fields `Beskrivning`, `kategori`, etc, from your `data` object are merged/copied into the product values of the resulting object

One solution to this would be as

```
/* Extract entry key/value pairs from products object */
Object.entries(products)
/* Reduce entry pairs to required object shape */
.reduce((result, [key, value]) => {

  /* Substitute for prior filter step. Avoid overhead of array copy
  between prior filter and this reduction. */
  if(value.Artikelgrupp !== data.Artikelgrupp) {
    return result;
  }

  /* Update result object, "upserting" fields of data object into 
  existing product value, for this reduce iteration */
  return {
    ...result,
    [ key ] : {
        ...value,
        Beskrivning: data.Beskrivning,
        kategori: data.kategori,
        status: data.status,
        synas: data.synas,
        tillverkare: data.tillverkare,
        titel: data.titel     
    }
  };

}, {})
```